# Problemas com Expressão Regular

Tags: sql, regex

Tenho o seguinte começo de *function* sql que vou utilizar para um sistema de recriação de *procedures/function* em C#

```
Create Function dbo.JN_FN_DataAtual(@TESTE INT)
```

E criei a expressão regular

```
(?si)\bCREATE\s*\bFUNCTION?\s*(?<owner>\w*.\b)(?<function>.*?\W)
```

Porem retornou os seguintes resultados:

1- dbo.

2- JN_FN_DataAtual(

Funcionou, porém não foi removido o ponto "." nem o parênteses "(".

O que pode ser?

Comment: Especifique a linguagem de programação ja que expressões regulares podem ser bem diferente entre elas. Também especifique melhor qual o objetivo da expressão regular, o que você quer extrair do texto.

Comment: texto alterado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o objetivo é extrair o nome do banco e o nome da procedure, essa seria mais simples:

```
Create Function ([^.]+)\.([^\(]+)
```

Um bom site pra testar expressões regulares é esse: http://www.regexr.com/